# Submit form (jquery) and show results in colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, colorbox

I have a form that I wish to submit which is posting to a php script to deal with the form data.

What I need to do is after hitting submit have a colorbox popup with the php results in it.

Can this be done?

This is what i've been trying:

```
$("#buildForm").click(function () { // #buildForm is button ID
    var data = $('#test-buildForm'); // #test-buildForm is form ID

    $("#buildForm").colorbox({
        href:"build_action.php", 
        iframe:true, 
        innerWidth:640, 
        innerHeight:360,
        data: data
    });
    return false;
     });
```

> UPDATE: This would need to be returned in an iframe as the
>   build_action.php has specific included css and js for those results.

Comment: Surely, it could be done. Where are you stuck? COuld you provide some code?

Comment: Please can you clarify what a colorbox is, as in a dialog box?

Comment: @Coulton is a popular jQuery plugin clone of lightbox

Answer (score 3):

This is simple, untested code but it'll give you a good jumping off point so you can elaborate however much you please:

```
<form action="/path/to/script.php" id="formID" method="post">
  <!-- form stuff goes here -->
  <input type="submit" name="do" value="Submit" />
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
    $("#formID").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $.colorbox({html:data});
        },
        'html');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could I have it in an iframe instead?

Comment: Also.. what would be on the php side now that it's serialized.

Comment: You'll need to write some PHP code to handle the form submission and print out the resulting HTML that you want displayed in the colorbox. In my example this would take place in "/path/to/script.php"

Comment: thanks... what about having it in an iframe? The script it's posting to is independant of the form page.

Comment: What do you mean?  Use an iframe instead of using colorbox?  Or use an iframe inside of the colorbox instead of the `html:data` option?  Also "the script it's posting to is independent of the form page." <== That doesn't make a difference and shouldn't affect how the ajax/colorbox functions

Comment: use an iframe inside of the colorbox instead of the html:data option

Comment: You shouldn't need to.  The ajax call to your PHP script will return HTML to the callback function and that when you're going to display it in the colorbox.

Comment: But the php script is an html page that has it's own css and js. Thats way I would need to have it in an iframe. Or do I have that wrong?

Comment: Hi @Jeff, Is it not possible to do this with an iframe?

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean...show me an example or something

Comment: Im stuck in an exactly same problem. Basically what he actually wanted is: to make POST request from an iframe INSIDE the colorbox, and get the result back in the same iframe. Ive tried setting data param, but it makes get request, not post. Also, on using jquery to make post request and then collect data inside colorbox will NOT make that data to be in the iframe. Also, For some reason, you cannot return iframe from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I ended up getting it to work:

```
<div id="formwrapper">
  <form method="post" action="http://wherever" target="response">
    # form stuff
  </form>

  <iframe id="response" name="response" style="display: none;"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
function hideresponseiframe() {
  $('#formwrapper #response').hide();
}

$('form').submit(
  function (event) {
    $('#formwrapper #response').show();
    $.colorbox(
      {
        inline: true,
        href: "#response",
        open: true,
        onComplete: function() {
          hideresponseiframe()
        },
        onClosed: function() {
          hideresponseiframe()
        }
      }
    );
    return true;
  }
);

</script>
```

Comment: Had to use this way because the "better one" from Jeff caused AJAX cross origin issues that could not be solved easily. But in my case, the callback "onComplete" was contra productive because it closes the output before anyone can see it at all.

Answer (score 1):

this article will help you with the problem

http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#demoForm').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            email : $('#email').val()
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#demoForm').show(500);
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#demoForm').show(500);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});



< ?php
sleep(3);

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = 'You did not enter you email.';
}
else {
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 'You\'ve entered: ' . $_POST['email'] . '.';
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to see the exact way to use your colorbox jQuery plugin.  But here is a basic (untested) code example that I've just written to hopefully get you on your way.

If you wish to submit a form using jQuery, assuming you have the following form and div to hold dialog data:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="num1" />
<input type="text" name="num2" />
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" />
</form>
<div style="display: hidden" id="dialogData"></div>
```

You can have a PHP code (doAddition.php), which might do the addition of the two numbers

```
<?php
// Do the addition
$addition = $_POST['num1'] + $_POST['num2'];

$result = array("result" => $addition);

// Output as json
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

You can use jQuery to detect the submitting of the code, then send the data to the PHP page and get the result back as JSON:

```
$('form#myForm').submit( function() {

    // Form has been submitted, send data from form and get result

    // Get data from form
    var formData = $('form#myForm').serialize();

    $.getJSON( 'doAddition.php', formData, function(resultJSON) {

          // Put the result inside the dialog case
          $("#dialogData").html(resultJSON.result);

          // Show the dialog
          $("#dialogData").dialog();

    });
});
```

Comment: This would need to be returned in an iframe as the script.php has specific included css and js for those results.

Comment: Couldn't you just give both pages access to the javascript and CSS?