# How to trigger a colorbox gallery with form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, colorbox

I have a document with two pages. The first one sends a folder name via form submit

```html
        <form method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="portfolio" value="directory">
            <input type="submit" value="author">
        </form>
```

the second one receives this folder name and open the files with glob function

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$directoryName = $_POST['portfolio'];
echo json_encode (glob($directoryName."/".'*.{jpg,mp4}', GLOB_BRACE));
?>
```

...finally images appear on the first page again via Ajax

```html
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "PAGE2.php",
                    data: data,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        var html = "";
                        $.each(response, function(i, val) {
                            var fileExtension = val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.'));
                            if (fileExtension == ".jpg") {
                                html += '<img src="'+val+'" height=250></img>';
                            }
                            else if (fileExtension == ".mp4") {
                                html += '<video width="320" height="240" src="'+val+'" type="video/mp4"controls autoplay loop></video>';
                            }
                        });
                        $("#display").html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

up to here no href tags...
I need to know how to display images like modal gallery with colorbox plugin.
I've tried this without success

```html
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                var data = $(this).serialize();
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "PAGE2.php",
                    data: data,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        var html = "";
                        $.each(response, function(i, val) {
                            var fileExtension = val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.'));
                            if (fileExtension == ".jpg") {
                                html += '<img src="'+val+'" height=250></img>';
                            }
                            else if (fileExtension == ".mp4") {
                                html += '<video width="320" height="240" src="'+val+'" type="video/mp4"controls autoplay loop></video>';
                            }
                        });
                        $("#display").html(html);
                        $("#link").colorbox({ inline:true, href: "#display"});
                    }
                });
            });
        }); 
<body>
    ... 
    <div id="display" style="display:none;"></div> 
    <a id="link" style="display:none"></a>
</body>
```

PAGE1.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() { 
            $("#formID").submit(function() {
                $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
                    $.colorbox({
                        html:data,
                        rel:'group1'
                    });
                },
                       'html');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="page2.php" method="post" id="formID">
            <input type="hidden" name="var" value="directory">
            <input type="submit" value="author">
        </form>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PAGE2.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page2</title>
</head>
    
<body>
<?php
$variable = $_POST['var'];
$img_dir = $variable . "/";
foreach(glob($img_dir . '*.jpg') as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'">'.'<img class="group">';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `colorbox` initializing code?

Comment: You mean the reference to jquery.colorbox.js file?

Comment: No, I do not see a slide show code in your snippet. So I assume you do not have one and with your current code, all the images and videos will be shown next to each other which would not be pretty. So I think it's better you take a better look at `jQuery.Colorbox` documentation and then you can add a simple class to all the images and videos, and then by using a `rel` option, group them together so colorbox will handle the slide show feature itself. for this, you first have to initialize the colorbox in your `$(document).ready()` like this: `$(".your-class").colorbox({rel:'your-group'});`

Comment: and then trigger your colorbox on your `ajax.done`

Comment: I checked the documentation but what I can not understand is how to link the colorbox initialization with my jquery (document).ready since I have to submit the form data in jquery. Perhaps via a callback function like   `$('#myform').bind('submit', function(){ $(".my-class").colorbox({rel:'my-group'}); $.ajax({...});});}`

Comment: Does [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehsant/6m3s0nbq/) so what you want?

Comment: I have a great confusion since I am just starting to use ajax. I need to make a gallery with depth levels. This means a page with various links or various buttons, each one a single gallery. Your example brings me closer but still it's not clear to me on how I can incorporate the submit method in jqXHR.done function before opening them with colorbox.

Comment: OK, in my example, I'm first sending an ajax request and after receiving the successful response back, I'm showing the colorbox. you are trying to do the same in your code. But now I have another question, You know that you can have an `iframe` in your colorbox. So if you want to show a complex page inside your colorbox, why not create it completely in your server-side and just simply put the result in your iframe colorbox instead of parsing the ajax response in JavaScript and try to format the html in JavaScript?

Comment: I really started learning jquery and ajax not too long ago. It is very difficult for me since there is a lot of information that I do not know. I have seen some examples of colorbox with iframe and I think they are closer to what I need.

Comment: I have seen the colorbox documentation. I tried with iframe but without success.
I have also seen available information in the web, specifically in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737166/submit-form-jquery-and-show-results-in-colorbox
so I've tried this:

Comment: I have edited my question above to show the code